# How to determine approximate maximum number of requests?

Tags: apache-2.2, mysql, php, load-testing

I'm building a quite simple web application, and need to get some rough understanding of how much load my server can take.

Of course, this depends on a whole lot of factors, but I just need a rough idea if we're talking about ten or ten thousand users, because at the moment I have no idea.

Standard LAMP-setup, with a quite small database and a reasonably simple and fast PHP. Each non-static request requires about 20 simple SQL queries. With no load, the runtime for such a request is around 50 ms. No explicit caching.

Current hosting is on a VPS w/ 1GB RAM and unknown CPU.

Is it possible to give a rough estimate given this? What is the bottleneck? CPU, RAM? Does 50 ms / request mean 20 requests per second? How much can caching help (factor 10? 100? 1000?)? Where would caching make most sense? How do I perform load-testing?

Uuh, lots of questions, not expecting detailed replies but would greatly appreciate pointers to where I can go from here to read up on system requirements/testing/possible ways of scaling up!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Number of users is pretty much irrelevant - the important thing is the number of hits and how quickly they are turned around. "quite small database" - this isn't really a very useful metric.

> Current hosting

So you've already got it setup and running? Then you are in a far position than us to estimate capacity. Start recording %D in your apache logs (if you're not already doing so) and logging mysql slow queries with a threshold of 0.

> Each non-static request requires about 20 simple SQL queries

erk! that's a lot of database round trips. Considered using joins (even cartesian joins for queries which return single rows can give a big performance boost) or server-side caching?

> Does 50 ms / request mean 20 requests per second?

No - it might mean it can process 500 requests in 50ms, or it might mean that it can only process one request every 50ms.

Go read some of [Steve Souder's](http://www.stevesouders.com/) stuff.

Limiting factor on your current system is probably memory (would your entire database and the files for the website fit into the memory available for caching? I suspect not).

Comment: Thanks a lot! Have implemented some pretty aggressive server-side caching, so DB roundtrips won't be the bottleneck. It will likely be memory, as you say.

Comment: Do you have any references for the '20 queries is a lot' claim? I'm currently trying to optimise a Joomla-based site and 20 queries per page request would be nirvana ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [Apache Bench](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/programs/ab.html) (`ab`).

Here's a random [example](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/689.cfm) 
and [another](http://www.developertutorials.com/tutorials/php/load-testing-your-web-application-with-apache-bench-316/).